# Improper resizing after using resize bar?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/chrismg12/zmbp7at3/88/.
There is a problem while using the resize bar along with a panel, containing a panel-header (of height 30px) and panel-body (of height auto),The panel itself resizes very fine, however the panel-header and body only increases in size but never decreases in size. I tried this with and without monaco-editor and have found that this is a problem with it rather than the resizing.

I have tried
1.fiddling with the style of panel-header and body.
2.I have tried adding the line:
    rightPane.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].style.width = rightPane.style.width;
    rightPane.childNodes[0].childNodes[1].style.width = rightPane.style.width;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Venti</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/lingtalfi/simpledrag/master/simpledrag.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style2.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/titlebar.css">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="title-bar">
  <div class="menu-button-container">
    <button 
      id="menu-button"
      class="menu-button"
    />
  </div>
  <div class="app-name-container">
    <p>App Name</p>
  </div>
  <div class="window-controls-container">
    <button 
      id="minimize-button"
      class="minimize-button"
    />
    <button 
      id="min-max-button"
      class="min-max-button"
    />
    <button 
      id="close-button"
      class="close-button"
    />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="panes-container">
  <div class="left-pane" id="left-pane">
  </div>
  <div class="panes-separator" id="panes-separator"></div>
  <div class="right-pane" id="right-pane">
    <div class="panel">
        <div class="panel-header">TABS</div>
        <div class="panel-body"><div id="editor"></div>
        <link rel="stylesheet" data-name="vs/editor/editor.main" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/monaco-editor/0.15.6/min/vs/editor/editor.main.css" />
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/monaco-editor/0.15.6/min/vs/loader.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/monaco-editor/0.15.6/min/vs/editor/editor.main.nls.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/monaco-editor/0.15.6/min/vs/editor/editor.main.js"></script>
        <script> 
          require.config({ paths: { 'vs': 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/monaco-editor/0.15.6/min/vs' }}) 
          require(['vs/editor/editor.main'], function() {
            var editor = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById('editor'), {
              value: "// Cross-browser xml parsing\nvar parseXML = function( data ) {\n  var xml, tmp;\n  if ( !data || typeof data !== \"string\" ) {\n    return null;\n  }\n  try {\n    if ( window.DOMParser ) { // Standard\n      tmp = new DOMParser();\n      xml = tmp.parseFromString( data , \"text/xml\" );\n    } else { // IE\n      xml = new ActiveXObject( \"Microsoft.XMLDOM\" );\n      xml.async = false;\n      xml.loadXML( data );\n    }\n  } catch( e ) {\n    xml = undefined;\n  }\n  if ( !xml || !xml.documentElement || xml.getElementsByTagName( \"parsererror\" ).length ) {\n    jQuery.error( \"Invalid XML: \" + data );\n  }\n  return xml;\n};\n\n// Bind a function to a context, optionally partially applying any arguments.\nvar proxy = function( fn, context ) {\n  var tmp, args, proxy;\n\n  if ( typeof context === \"string\" ) {\n    tmp = fn[ context ];\n    context = fn;\n    fn = tmp;\n  }\n\n  // Quick check to determine if target is callable, in the spec\n  // this throws a TypeError, but we will just return undefined.\n  if ( !jQuery.isFunction( fn ) ) {\n    return undefined;\n  }\n\n  // Simulated bind\n  args = core_slice.call( arguments, 2 );\n  proxy = function() {\n    return fn.apply( context || this, args.concat( core_slice.call( arguments ) ) );\n  };\n\n  // Set the guid of unique handler to the same of original handler, so it can be removed\n  proxy.guid = fn.guid = fn.guid || jQuery.guid++;\n\n  return proxy;\n};\n\nSound.play = function() {}\nSound.prototype = { something; }\nSound.prototype.play = function() {}\nSound.prototype.play = myfunc\nvar parser = document.createElement('a');\nparser.href = \"http://example.com:3000/pathname/?search=test#hash\";\nparser.hostname; // => \"example.com\"",
              language: 'javascript',
              automaticLayout: true,
              fontSize:18
            });
          });
        </script></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<div class="footbar"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the JS code to be used:

```
var leftPane = document.getElementById('left-pane');
var rightPane = document.getElementById('right-pane');
var paneSep = document.getElementById('panes-separator');
var leftLimit = 0;
var rightLimit = 90;


paneSep.sdrag(function (el, pageX, startX, pageY, startY, fix) {

    fix.skipX = true;

    if (pageX < window.innerWidth * leftLimit / 100) {
        pageX = window.innerWidth * leftLimit / 100;
        fix.pageX = pageX;
    }
    if (pageX > window.innerWidth * rightLimit / 100) {
        pageX = window.innerWidth * rightLimit / 100;
        fix.pageX = pageX;
    }

    var cur = pageX / window.innerWidth * 100;
    if (cur < 0) {
        cur = 0;
    }
    if (cur > window.innerWidth) {
        cur = window.innerWidth;
    }


    var right = (100-cur-2);
    leftPane.style.width = cur + '%';
    rightPane.style.width = right + '%';

}, null, 'horizontal');
```

Here are the expected results:
- Resize bar works.
- monaco-editor resizes properly (can decrease and increase in width).
Here are the actual results:
- Resize bar works.
- monaco-editor only resizes when panel (or right-pane)'s width increases and not when it decreases.

Answer (score 1):

I've been dealing with the same problem for about 10 hours. I figured out that if you have a parent container with `display: flex; justify-content: row`, the layout engine skips over setting the width. If you switch it to `justify-content: column` instead, it doesn't have this problem. Why? I have pushed my eyes through the back of my skull trying to figure it out and still have no clue.

Anyway. My first solution was to set a class on it of `.narrow {width: 90%}`, then I put a listener for `onDidLayoutChange` and removed the class. This "worked" because it forced Monaco to render with a width constraint then render again to the width I wanted, but you had the noticeable jumping around of Monaco.

I finally figured out that you can **set `max-width: 90%` on your Monaco container div and it essentially eliminates the problem**. You can obviously change the percentage to what you want. Make sure you have `overflow: none` on your body to prevent scrollbars from ruining your day.

In my case:

```
<div class="ide-container">
    <div class="file-browser">
    <div class="text-editor"><div id="monacodiv"></div></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.ide-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 100%;
}
.file-browser {
  flex-basis: 15%;
}
.text-editor {
  flex: 1 1 0;
  max-width: 85%;
}
```